# Hexadecimal conversion without using toString("X")

Tags: c#, hex

```
private byte[] presetChksum(byte newvalue)
    {
        int calcSum = 0x00 + 0x00 + 0xfe + 0x00 + 0x00 + 0x00 + 0x00 + 0x00 + 0x01 + 0x00 + 0x00 + 0x01 + 0x51 + 0x13 + 0x01 + 0x00;

        
        byte[] data = new byte[2];
        
        data[0] = (byte) (calcSum >> 8);
        data[1] = (byte) (calcSum & 0xff);
        
        return data;
    }
```

currently calcSum value is 357d, but I want the hex value of 0x165. I cant use calcSum.toString("X") because, although I get the correct value of calcSum, it throws the values in data array off - instead of getting the high and low byte 0x16 0x05, I get the hexadecimal value of 165d, 0xA5 0x00. Hope I have explained this adequately!
I was thinking about using modulos of 16, but that sounds like unnecessary amounts of coding to achieve what I feel should be simple!

Comment: But 357 decimal is 0x165. 0x1605 is 5637.. The two byes in 0x165 are 0x01 and 0x65, not 0x16 and 0x05

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check - it looks very much like the protocol document I've been given is wrong.

Comment: Feel free to chuck a scan/photo/copypasta of it up so we can help interpret!

Comment: Thanks Caius! Much appreciated. I think I've actually cracked it. The protocol document looked like it copied and pasted elements from one section to another without changing the check sum equation. As I didn't have the device to test it, I didn't ever consider the document was at fault!